# change EditText to TextView

Tags: java, android

I want to change the `TextView` to `EditText` and the `TextView` to `EditText`, therefore I decided to use the `ViewSwitcher` element on android, I read about it on the [android developer website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html).

However I still have some point that I don't understand:

1. How can I determine the current switch? (for example, to show only the `EditText`, and to invisible the `TextView`)

Here is my code:

```xml
 <ViewSwitcher
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_switcher"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clickable_text_view"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="TextViewClicked"
            android:text="@string/some_value" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hidden_edit_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/some_value" >
        </EditText>
    </ViewSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are complicating quite simple task. Put your `EditText` and `TextView` into `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and just do `setVisibility()` on them hidding one and showing another when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_switcher"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickable_text_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="TextViewClicked"
        android:text="@string/some_value" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/hidden_edit_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/some_value" >
</EditText>
```

And change visibility of `EditText` or `TextView` from code, whenever you want.

Note: for default `TextView` invisible.

Hope it's help.